# What I need to replace to improve perfomance of the alghorithm?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am new in Matlab but I am trying.
I have the following code:

```
for t = 1:size(data,2)
  b = data(t)/avevalue;
  if b >= 1
     cat1 = [repmat((avevalue),floor(b),1)',mod(data(t),15)];
  else
     cat1 = data(t);
  end
  modified = [modified,cat1];
end
```

The answer for

```
data=[16 18 16 25 17 7 15];
avevalue=15;
```

is

```
    15     1    15     3    15     1    15    10    15     2     7    15     0
```

But when my array is more than 10000 elements it working very, impossibly slow (for 100000 nearly 3 minutes, for example). How can I increase its speed?

Comment: Use [the profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html). How is processing 2 *million* elements in 3 minutes slow?

Comment: At the very least, you are growing `modified` with each iteration of your loop. This is going to be tremendously slow, as MATLAB needs to copy the array in memory every time.

Comment: Sorry, its a mistake about 2 millions. Its their summary size (length*width). Its because of my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main reasons for the slowness:

1. The fact that you are using a loop.
2. The output array is growing on each iteration.

you can improve runtime by trying the following approach:

```
%auxilliary array
divSumArray = ceil((data+1)/avevalue);

%defines output array
newArr = ones(1,sum(divSumArray))*avevalue;

%calculates modulo
moduloDataIndices = cumsum(divSumArray);

%assigning modulo in proper location
newArr(moduloDataIndices) = mod(data,avevalue);
```

the final result

```
15     1    15     3    15     1    15    10    15     2     7    15     0
```

**Time measurement**

I measured runtime for the following input:

```
n = 30000;
data = randi([0 99],n,1);
avevalue=15;
```

original algo:

```
Elapsed time is 11.783951 seconds.
```

optimized algo:

```
Elapsed time is 0.007728 seconds.
```

Comment: Using a loop is not necessarily slower.

Comment: @excaza, not necessarily, but usually it is. see
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html


also, my runtime measurements showed significant time improvement

Comment: Yes, I am aware that vectorization is *generally* faster. That does not mean that the absolute "loops are slow" is true. As the JIT compiler improves, so too does loop speed.

Comment: I didn't say that loop is "necessarily slower". I just mentioned that in this case it made the code slower.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing.  For numbers greater than 2*avevalue, you'll have more than 2 elements.  There's just no test case of that sort in the example.

Comment: @Peter thank you for your comment. I updated the code to support numbers greater than 2*avevalue as well